# Scalacheck OutOfMemory exception

Tags: scala, scalatest

Sure I must be overlooking something but here is what's happening

```
object MenuTreeArbitrary extends Properties("MenuTree") {

   lazy val genMenuDetails: Gen[MenuDetails] = for {
         id <- arbitrary[Int]
         label <- arbitrary[String]
         itemType <- arbitrary[String]
         formId <- arbitrary[Int]

        ms <- arbitrary[String]
        mv<- arbitrary[JsValue]
        items <- Gen.lzy(genMenuDetails)

      } yield MenuDetails(Some(id), label, itemType, Some(formId), Some(Map(ms->mv)), Some(List(items)))

 implicit lazy val menuDetailsArb: Arbitrary[MenuDetails] = Arbitrary(genMenuDetails)

  lazy val genMenuTree: Gen[MenuTree] = for {
      id <- arbitrary[Int]
       rootOrgId <- arbitrary[Int]
      isForMobile <- arbitrary[Boolean]
      otherJson <- Gen.lzy(arbitrary[MenuDetails])

  } yield MenuTree(id, Some(rootOrgId), isForMobile, otherJson)

 }
```

And test is

```
test("using generators "){

forAll(genMenuTree) { m: MenuTree =>
  val json = Json.toJson(m)
  val mt = Json.fromJson[MenuTree](json)
  val t = mt match{
    case res : JsSuccess[MenuTree] => res.get 

  }
  t should be (m)
}
```

}

While executing forAll(genMenuTree) it throws OutOfMemory on recursive call though code is using Gen.lzy. Any idea?

```
rg.scalatest.exceptions.GeneratorDrivenPropertyCheckFailedException: Exception "java.lang.StackOverflowError" (included as the TestFailedException's cause) was thrown during argument generation.
at org.scalatest.prop.Checkers$.doCheck(Checkers.scala:453)
at org.scalatest.prop.GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks$class.forAll(GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks.scala:915)
```